# Stop socat from terminating when other end closes

Tags: socat

I'd like to redirect an applications input and output to a unix socket and connect to that socket from another session. What I'm doing so far is the following:

On the "server" side:

```
socat EXEC:"command" UNIX-LISTEN:/tmp/comm
```

And on the "client" side:

```
socat UNIX-CONNECT:/tmp/comm -
```

It works pretty good, but as soon as the client-side `socat` terminates, the server terminates, too. But I'd like it to keep running and reconnect later... How do I accomplish that?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You must use `fork` option, which handle a connection in a child process, make the parent process attempt to handle more connections.

In first terminal:

```
$ socat - UNIX-LISTEN:/tmp/comm,fork
```

In second terminal:

```
$ socat UNIX-CONNECT:/tmp/comm -
```

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> in second terminal, switch to the first terminal and see your server is still running.